# MySQL Database table from PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I have attempted to create a mysql query to create the database schema but with no success, here is the php code that get data from the database, could you please help me create a mysql script that will create the database tables?

here is the php script:

```
    foreach($string["statuses"] as $status) {
    $selectSQL = 'SELECT * FROM twitter WHERE t_id="'.$status["id"].'" ';
    $queryset = '';
    $queryset = $mysqli->query ($selectSQL);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($queryset)==0)
        { 
        $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["text"]);
        $loc = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["user"]["location"]);
        $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["user"]["id"]);
        $app = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["source"]);
        $img = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["user"]["profile_image_url"]);
        $retweet = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["retweet_count"]);
        $favorite = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $status["favorite_count"]);

        $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `twitter` VALUES (NULL,"'.$status['id'].'","'.$text.'","'.$status['created_at'].'","'.$loc.'","'.$user_id.'","'.$app.'","'.$img.'","'.$retweet.'","'.$favorite.'")');
        }   
}
```

Comment: What tables? What fields would those tables have? Those fields would have what data type?

Comment: The code above selects and inserts data from/to existing tables. It does not create any tables. Are you saying you've written this code before designing your tables? It's not clear what the situation is. If you need to create tables, go and google the CREATE TABLE syntax...or use a GUI tool like MySQL Workbench to just input them. We don't know what fields and data types you want anyway, so it's a bit tricky to give specific code. As an aside - re the above code, learn to use parameterised queries, it will save you syntax pain and also reduce your vulnerability to Injection attacks

Comment: May you should start by using prepared statements http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: no i'm saying -- i need t create a table that contains the following $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `twitter` VALUES (NULL,"'.$status['id'].'","'.$text.'","'.$status['created_at'].'","'.$loc.'","'.$user_id.'","'.$app.'","'.$img.'","'.$retweet.'","'.$favorite.'")');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp

You have to write the SQL yourself though.

Comment: A link to the official documentation would be better IMO: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html . W3Schools is ok for some things but is also well-known to have inaccuracies or incomplete information in places.

Answer (score 1):

First, some nomenclature;

This:

$mysqli->query('INSERT INTO twitter VALUES (NULL,"'.$status['id'].'","'.$text.'","'.$status['created_at'].'","'.$loc.'","'.$user_id.'","'.$app.'","'.$img.'","'.$retweet.'","'.$favorite.'")');

is a command to place data into a table that already EXISTS, unless you want a table of PHP MySQL query strings, which I'm thinking you do not.

In either case, you will need to read up on the CREATE TABLE section of MySQL, and learn how to create a table in MySQL. Your question is unclear, and no one will just do the work for you here. Stack Overflow is a learning place.

If you want to have an elephant circus, you'll need to know about elephants...or hire an elephant trainer.

Once you understand how to create the table, you can learn how to read (query) it, insert into it (as this query does), remove entries, alter the table structures, and more. This will require some PHP knowledge, unless you choose another scripting language, like Ruby or Perl, and you'll want to have a pleasant database manager to view your db; my personal favorite is Adminer, available at 
http://adminer.org

There are others, which you can Google easily. Good luck with your work.